# Updating result from ajax calls in partial views in asp.net mvc2

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a ASP.Net MVC 2 partial view like the one below,

**FORM 1:**

```
<div id="d1">
    <%  using (Ajax.BeginForm("ManageSources", "Sources",
    saveAjaxOptions))
    { %>
```

... all this form's html markup goes here

```
  <div id="src_Parameters"></div>

    <% } %>
</div>
```

**Form 2**

```
<%  using (Ajax.BeginForm("FetchParameters", "Sources",
    fetchAjaxOptions))
    { %>
```

hidden fields to send values to the action method go here
.. button to post this form

```
<% } %>
```

Now, in the fetchAjaxOptions, i have given the target div to be `src_Parameters`, which resides inside the form1, when i post the second form, i am being returned a partial view as the only view page, instead of populating the results in the `src_Parameters` div.

How do i accomplish this. Actually the results of the `FetchParameters` ajax call should be able to be posted for the `ManageSources` ajax call.

Where is the problem or will nesting the forms workout since this is using ajax forms.. Kindly suggest me the right procedure to do this task.

Comment: Can you please add how have you defined : fetchAjaxOptions,saveAjaxOptions

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your server side code, but I suspect you have forgotten to have set the return type to be a partial view.

```
public PartialViewResult FetchParameters()
{
    //do some stuff
    return PartialView(“_ViewName”, viewModel)
}
```

It could also be that you fotgot to add a reference to the Microsoft Ajax

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I have added these javascript references and am using the PartialViewResult in the controller method..`public PartialViewResult FetchSourceParameters(string viewId, string srcContent, string ctype){.....return PartialView("SourceContentParameters");}`, even though i see the url being changed to this partial view's url. And, i am not using any viewmodel to be bound.